# Cannot assume role through AWS config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, botocore

We've always used the following to assume a role for longer than an hour on a remote machine:

```
# Prep environment to use roles.
unset AWS_CONFIG_FILE
unset AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE

CONFIG_FILE=$(mktemp)

# Creates temp file with instance profile credentials as default
# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, ROLE_ARN are available from the environment.
printf "[default]\naws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\naws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\n[profile role_profile]\nrole_arn = $ROLE_ARN\nsource_profile = default" > $CONFIG_FILE

# make sure instance profile takes precedence
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=$CONFIG_FILE
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=role_profile
```

Unfortunately, this method recently started to fail. We can reproduce the failure just by running:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Adding the `--debug` flag to the last command:

```
09:11:47 2018-06-21 14:11:47,731 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.15.40 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.9.76-3.78.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.10.40
...
09:11:47 2018-06-21 14:11:47,811 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.sts.GetCallerIdentity: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f22d19a6ed8>
09:11:47 2018-06-21 14:11:47,812 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - WARNING - Refreshing temporary credentials failed during mandatory refresh period.
09:11:47 Traceback (most recent call last):
09:11:47   File "/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 432, in _protected_refresh
...
09:11:47     raise KeyError(cache_key)
09:11:47 KeyError: 'xxxx' (redacted)
09:11:47 2018-06-21 14:11:47,814 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255
```

Apparently a key is missing from a Python "cache" dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

The obvious solution is just to find and remove the cache:

```
rm ~/.aws/cli/cache/*
```

This doesn't explain how this started happening, though (and if it will happen again). Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: I cannot explain why it happened, but one of the JSON file in the cache was malformed and the JSON decoder threw an error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` while trying to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the permissions inside `~/.aws/cli` are wrong.

Check the permissions:

```
ls -la ~/.aws/cli
ls -la ~/.aws/cli/cache
```

It might be possible that your files have wrong permissions or ownership. Correct them and `aws cli` commands would work correctly.

The permissions needed for files inside `~/.aws/cli/cache` are `-rw-------`.

Hope it helps.